# How to validate a form

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I do have a html form which takes username and password as input . On button click , wrote a js function which would hit the api asynchronously . Before that , how would i validate it

```
 <form>
        <div><label id="resultString"></label></div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Login</legend>
            Username: <input type="text" id="username"><br><br>
            Password: <input type="password" id="password"><br><br>
            <input type="button" onclick="submitdetails();" value="Login">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

My js function is :

```
function submitdetails() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var params = JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password });
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200) 
            document.getElementById("resultString").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        else
            document.getElementById("resultString").innerHTML = "Error"; 
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("POST","http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/",true);     
    xmlhttp.send(params);
}
```

Comment: use jquery validator plugin.

Comment: From the javascript function itself you can able to validate the details.

Comment: Read the [help/on-topic] before asking a question. You are asking for API which is NOT on topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <script>
function submitdetails() {
var username = $("#username").val();
   var password = $("#passwords").val();
 if(username==""||password=="")
 {
alert("please fill");
}
var params = JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password });
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200) 
        document.getElementById("resultString").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    else
        document.getElementById("resultString").innerHTML = "Error"; 
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("POST","http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/",true);     
xmlhttp.send(params);
```

}

Answer (score 2):

```
<form id='form' name='form' method='post' action=''>
        <div><label id="resultString"></label></div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Login</legend>
            Username: <input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br><br>
            Password: <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br><br>
            <input type="button" value="Login">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

And this is the validator plugin code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#form').validate({
    rules: {
      username: {
        required: true
      },
      password: {
        required: true
      }

    },
    highlight: function(element) {
      $(element).closest('.form-control').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
    },
    success: function(element) {

      $(element).closest('.form-control').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
    }
  });
});
```

refer: https://jqueryvalidation.org/

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/18404fvz/)

**THINGS TO REMEMBER**

1. Your form should have a name and id
2. I say, give name and id for all fields as well
3. Use submit handler to do the call you did on onclick

Comment: I would precise there is nothing telling OP want/accept to use JQuery ;)

Comment: The tag is for javascript, not jQuery. Do you know how to write this in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    var y = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    if (x == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(myForm.email.value))
  {
    return (true)
  }
    alert("You have entered an invalid email address!")
    return (false)
}


</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp"
onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<br/>
email: <input type="text" name="email">
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

---

But its easy to use use jQuery validate plugin

Demo : https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/

Documentation : https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

sample code -

```
$("#signupForm").validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: "required",
            lastname: "required",
            username: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            confirm_password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                equalTo: "#password"
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            topic: {
                required: "#newsletter:checked",
                minlength: 2
            },
            agree: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
            lastname: "Please enter your lastname",
            username: {
                required: "Please enter a username",
                minlength: "Your username must consist of at least 2 characters"
            },
            password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
            },
            confirm_password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long",
                equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
            },
            email: "Please enter a valid email address",
            agree: "Please accept our policy"
        }
    });
```

Comment: I would precise there is nothing telling OP want/accept to use JQuery ;)

Comment: The question is tagged as javascript, not jQuery.

Comment: yup first one is pure JavaScript based validation and 2nd one is jQuery validate plugin code ...

Answer (score 0):

using following conditions

```
if(username ==null || username =="")
{
 document.getEelementById("showerr").innerHTML = "is empty";
}
if(password==null || password =="" password.length  < 6)
{
 document.getEelementById("showerr").innerHTML = "must 6 or above characters";
}
```

HTML :

```
<span id="showerr"></span>
```

using regular expression you can validate

http://jsfiddle.net/ghvj4gy9/embedded/result,js/